# Getting different color while setting from InterfaceBuilder and through code

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, interface-builder

I'm setting some border to `UITextField` via `UIView` extension which looks like below.

```
extension UIView {

    func border(side: BorderSide = .all, color:UIColor = UIColor.black, borderWidth:CGFloat = 1.0) {

        let border = CALayer()
        border.borderColor = color.cgColor
        border.borderWidth = borderWidth

        switch side {
        case .all:
            self.layer.borderWidth = borderWidth
            self.layer.borderColor = color.cgColor
        case .top:
            border.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width:self.frame.size.width ,height: borderWidth)
        case .bottom:
            border.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: self.frame.size.height - borderWidth, width:self.frame.size.width ,height: borderWidth)
        case .left:
            border.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: borderWidth, height: self.frame.size.height)
        case .right:
            border.frame = CGRect(x: self.frame.size.width - borderWidth, y: 0, width: borderWidth, height: self.frame.size.height)
        case .cusomRight:
            border.frame = CGRect(x: self.frame.size.width - borderWidth - 8, y: 8, width: borderWidth, height: self.frame.size.height - 16)
        }

        if side.rawValue != 0 {
            self.layer.addSublayer(border)
            self.layer.masksToBounds = true
        }

    }
}
```

and getting effect via this line.

```
let color = UIColor.hexStringToUIColor(hex: "#1F271B")
txtLongitude.border(side: .bottom, color: color, borderWidth: 1)
```

while for another I was taking `UIView` as border of `UITextView`. and giving background color from InterfaceBuilder. Which is shown in below screenshot.
[image: Setting color via InterfaceBuilder]

But When I run application. I'm getting different color which I gave through `InterfaceBuilder`.
Here are screenshot.
[image: Color which is gave by code]
[image: Color which is gave by InterfaceBuilder]

I can set both color by coding but I want to know why this is happening, while I'm setting color from InterfaceBuilder?

Comment: i think it is in correct color, if you want to check in excatly change the background color to white and check once

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had this issue before
in the marked button in the image below choose from the drop list `Device RGB` instead of `Generic RGB` 
and you will find those values making the color you want programmatically

[image]